# To run tests on different browsers using Selenium webdriver+ TestNG+Java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng

I am trying to run my tests using Selenium web driver + TestNG + Java, everything runs fine with Firefox, but when I tried to extend it to different browsers like IE and Chrome, I have included code for it, but it doesn't seem to work. I am using some excel files to pass input while automating it. Thanks in advance

Comment: Please post some code

Comment: Please Elaborate more

Comment: Thank you for your reply,to run my tests in firefox I am using Driver= new FirefoxDriver, and then  I am using if(browser.equalsIgnoreCase("IE"))
  {
   System.out.println("IE webdriver would be used");
   DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
   capabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS, true);
   System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "C:\\Program Files\\IEDriverServer_Win32_2.35.1\\IEDriverServer.exe");
      wd = new InternetExplorerDriver();
  } to run it through IE, using XML file

Answer (score 0):

Required Configuration with IE

1.The IEDriverServer exectuable must be downloaded and placed in your PATH.

2.On IE 7 or higher on Windows Vista or Windows 7, you must set the Protected Mode settings for each zone to be the same value. The value can be on or off, as long as it is the same for every zone. To set the Protected Mode settings, choose "Internet Options..." from the Tools menu, and click on the Security tab. For each zone, there will be a check box at the bottom of the tab labeled "Enable Protected Mode".

3.The browser zoom level must be set to 100% so that the native mouse events can be set to the correct coordinates.

**Check if java plugin is installed in your browser.**

For more info go to http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver

Answer (score 0):

You cannot work with chrome/IE same as Firefox. In order to work with that you need [chrome](https://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/downloads/list)/[IE](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/downloads/list)  driver, which is an executive file. The code for invoking the chrome and IE is a little different than Firefox.

For chrome you can take help from [here](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver)
For IE you can take help from [here](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver)

example for invoking driver

```
if(BrowserName.equalsIgnoreCase("Firefox")){
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
}else if(BrowserName.equalsIgnoreCase("Chrome")){
    String ChromeDriverPath= "D:\\ChromeDriver\\chromedriver.exe";
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", ChromeDriverPath);
    driver=new ChromeDriver();
}else if(BrowserName.equalsIgnoreCase("IE")){
    IEDriverPath32bit= "D:\\IEDriver\\IEDriverServer.exe";
    System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", IEDriverPath32bit);
```

Comment: yes, I have added drivers for IE and Chrome, and uses those things in @beforeMethod annotation, in almost same way as you have said. and passing parameters like 'broswer' in XML file. And I am using desired capability feature. I am able to generate 2 firefox browsers, but not differnt broswers like Firefox and IE

Comment: @Aruna: I think `String ChromeDriverPath= "D:\\ChromeDriver\\chromedriver.exe";`
    `System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", ChromeDriverPath);`
    `driver=new ChromeDriver();` should work. Please put it on Before class annotation method hard coded (I mean just for testing do not take any value from xml)